# Facebook: Account Creation Date

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am wondering if anybody knows of any efficient ways of making a guess on working out the account creation date.

We're making a voting system which utilises Facebook and we want to block fresh accounts from taking part.

I understand that due to our use case we can't even apply for read_stream as they don't allow applications to use it for cases like this. Seems like a bit of a pain anyway with the amount of pagination requests we'd have to make, could be a case of maybe 10 separate API requests per user which would be silly.

One way I've read about is [getting it from the UID](http://metadatascience.com/2013/03/11/inferring-facebook-account-creation-date-from-facebook-user-id/) but I still don't quite understand how we'd work this out.

Has anybody else got any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: No there is no good way to know the age of an account and it is on purpose.

Comment: Can I have a reason or am I just going to be left hanging?

Comment: There is no API for it. If we wanted you to do it there would be an API to get join date.

Comment: Yes I know that but that isn't really the reason for it being "on purpose". Do you have any suggestions in getting some kind of date? The only answer I can think of is making an pointless feature addition to the system in order to get accepted for read_stream. I don't need the exact creation date but I'd like a date where it goes back as far as possible.

Comment: read_stream doesn't exists so you will never get approved for that. You would need user_posts permission but it wouldn't get approved for getting account creation date.